# How to update a database entry from a dropdown in Laravel 4

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, laravel-4, sql-update, eloquent

I have a users table that references a company_id from the companies table. I have successfully populated a company dropdown in the edit user view, but when I change the company and click Save, it does not update the user table entry to reflect the new company:

UserController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = $this->user->find($id);

    // build a select list of companies
    $options = DB::table('companies')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->lists('name', 'id');

    // get the existing company for the user
    $selected = Input::old('company') ? Input::old('company') : $user->company->id;

    if (is_null($user))
    {
        return Redirect::route('users.index');
    }

    return View::make('users.edit', array( 'options' => $options, 'selected' => $selected ), compact('user'));
}
```

And in the view I have this for the dropdown:

```
    {{ Form::label('company', 'Company:') }}
    {{ Form::select('company', $options, $selected) }}
```

I suspect my $selected variable is interfering somehow, so what would be the best way to tell the update method to ignore the previous $selected value if a new value has been selected in the dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

I was making that way too complicated. The $selected variable is unnecessary, as I had a typo in my table column reference. Here is what works:

```
{{ Form::label('company_id', 'Company:') }}
{{ Form::select('company_id', $options ) }}
```

As you can see, when I matched my select id ('company_id' instead of 'company') to the field as described in my model, Laravel links and updates them as expected.